# Can't unit test a method which calls a static method, how can I re-design this program?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, oop, static

I have a class which writes logs to a text file throughout the program. I thought it would be a good idea to make the methods `static` as it only has a few methods and is called in lots of different parts of the program. This method is called once at the start of the program to create the initial file.

```
public static void CreateAuditLog()
{
    var fileName = Path.Combine(filePath, 
        $@"AuditFile{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-fff}.txt");

    writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(fileName,
        FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write));

    GetAuditLogFileSize();
}
```

However when coming to writing unit tests, I didn't know that you can't test a method which calls a static method. (example method from code base)

```
public Decimal CalculateCurrentBalance
{
    get
    {
        var balance = TotalAmountBilled - TotalAmountPaid;
        Audit.Message(2, $"Balance: {balance} for: {Name}");
        return TotalAmountBilled - TotalAmountPaid;
    }
}
```

the message method has a lot of details so I won't post it all here, but basically it takes in a number and a message to log to the text file. The stream writer is purposely left open in `CreateAuditLog()` so that `Message()` could be called in lots of different places and the messages would be written to the log file.

```
public static void Message(int auditLevel, string message)
```

I feel like the way I have designed this program is bad. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can re-design this? I am not sure how I can do this without creating an instance of my logging class on every single other class in the program.

Comment: "you can't test a method which calls a static method" It depends on what that static method is doing. Statics make testing difficult in that they can't be mocked (easily?). Mocking is useful for dependencies--specifically dependencies that form integration points in your code (e.g. databases, web services, file systems, etc.). Calling `Math.Add` probably isn't going to make your code un-testable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't *create* an instance in every other class; **inject** one.

This is one of the fundamentals of unit testing; Dependency Injection. Classes don't create or directly access their dependencies, they are passed the one to use. In this case, if your `Log` class implemented `ILogger` (an interface you make up) then your class would look like:

```
public class MyInjectedClass
{
     private readonly ILogger logger;
     public MyInjectedClass(ILogger logger)
     {
        this.logger = logger;
     }

     public void SomeMethod()
     {
        logger.Message();
     }
}
```

Of course, now you have to pass an instance of `ILogger` all over the place and that's a big hassle. Luckily there are lots of libraries like `NInject` and `Autofac` that will wire up all the dependencies for you. It will take some refactoring but once you are done you just register your logging class as a singleton for the `ILogger` interface and it will be automagically injected into every class that has it as a dependency.

(MS has a DI library as well included with .NET Core if you are using that)

The interface could look something like:

```
public interface ILogger
{
     void Message(string msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I haven't really worked with interfaces before. What would the code look like to create an instance of ILogger?

Comment: @kerberonix Sounds like you need to do some reading/studying on OOP principles :). Added a sample interface; but understanding how to use them (and inheritance/polymorphism in general) is crazy important in C# and similar languages.

Comment: @kerberonix Just realized I may have misinterpreted your question. You don't create instances of interfaces (only of classes that implement them). In a DI framework the injection container does the instantiation for you, otherwise you just new up the concrete class.